# How to precisely find thumb position of input [type="range"]?

Tags: css, slider, range

The idea was to put a tooltip with value related to slider. I thought initially to accomplish that task by using css `grid`. CSS provides you with grid of any size, 10 or 1000 cols, doesn't matter. By utilizing grid functionality, we can align out tooltip as we wish.
What we really get is:

[image: thumb is unstable]

Thumb position is sort of unpredictable. It seems that it is being offset, and the direction of that offset is dependent on whether input value is in the left or right part of slider.

*Note:* default thumb behaves exactly the same way. I mean, shape of thumb is not of concern.

**So, how does html calculate position of thumb based on its value?**

Comment: am sure it's a division with some rounding and due to this rounding you won't have exactly what you expect

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Are you trying to find the value of the slider? You could try using the `granularity` property and setting it to one in that case -- that way you will have access to the right value divided by 10.

Comment: @Temani Afif May be. Is the algorithm of calculation available anywhere? 



@DanielThompson I'm not talking about `granularity`, which is equal to *one* by default and can be modified via `step` attribute. My question is stated pretty obviously - position of thumb in any measurable unit at any point of time. Please, see image provided for visual perception of question.

Answer (score 17):

For anyone else stumbling upon this problem, the issue is that the first and last position of thumb are offset by half the width of `thumb`. Because of this, all of the other positions are slightly offset to compensate for the first and last one.

One simple solution for this is to normalize the thumb position between actual first and last thumb positions which are actually `0 + halfThumb` and `width - halfThumb` respectively.

To normalize, we can use the formula recommended in this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/281164).

So the `left` offset of absolutely positioned element in `px` would be:

```
const left = (((value - minValue) / (valueMax - valueMin)) * ((totalInputWidth - thumbHalfWidth) - thumbHalfWidth)) + thumbHalfWidth;
```

Where

`value` is actual input value.

`minValue` is actual minimum value for input.

`maxValue` is actual maximum value for input.

`thumbHalfWidth` is half of the width of thumb used for slider drag.

`totalInputWidth` is width of input element in pixels.

Answer (score 5):

You have to take into consideration the size of your `thumb`

It is possible to achieve this using a little bit of javascript (unless you can get the range ratio which I am not aware of as of now)

## Therorical

Calculate the `ratio` of your current `value` relative to the `min` and `max` of your input (between 0 and 1)

```
(value - el.min) / (el.max - el.min)
```

So its position (starting from the arrow relative to the input container) would be:

```
thumbSize / 2 + ratio * 100% - ration * thumbSize
```

## Method

This might give an idea of how to implement this in javascript

```
const thumbSize = 10
const range = document.querySelector('input[type=range]')
const tooltip = document.querySelector('.tooltip')

range.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const ratio = (range.value - range.min) / (range.max - range.min)
  tooltip.style.left = `calc(${thumbSize / 10}px + ${ratio * 100} - ${ratio} * ${thumbSize}px)`
}
```

This above code has not been tested but the same method has been implemented